# How to use Windows key shortcuts in Azure bastion connection to remote Windows VM?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

Pressing Windows + R on Azure Bastion connection to Windows VM results in run dialogue displaying on my local Windows PC instead of the remote VM.  Is there a way to use the Windows key shortcuts on the remote VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to use the Windows key shortcuts on the remote VM via the Azure Bastion connection as the Azure Bastion service is a new fully platform-managed PaaS service. It provides secure and seamless RDP/SSH connectivity to your virtual machines directly **in the Azure portal over SSL**.

When you connect to remote VM via Azure Bastion, Azure Bastion uses an HTML5 based web client that is automatically **streamed to your local device**, so that you get your RDP/SSH session over SSL on port 443 enabling you to traverse corporate firewalls securely. In fact, in this case, you are not directly connecting to the remote VM in an RDP session. Currently, Azure Bastion also does not help direct the windows key to the remote VM.

As a workaround, you can use the Windows key shortcuts on the remote VM via KeyBoard redirection on the remote desktop connection. As the picture displayed, select the `Apply Windows key combinations on the remote computer` when you directly connect to the remote Azure VM with the remote desktop connection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way (& only) I've found is by using the on-screen keyboard

The Windows key is sticky, so it's just two mouse clicks